# data frame with as many words as the numbers in another column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':['foo','bar'], 'n':[3,5]})
```

I'd like to create a data frame with as many words in `w` as the number in the corresponding `n` row:

```
0 foo
1 foo
2 foo
3 bar
4 bar
5 bar
6 bar
7 bar
8 bar
```

Comment: Must be a dup: `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['n']), 'w']`

Comment: Or `np.repeat(df['w'], df['n'])`